# How to instantiate a new JSONObject Arraylist which takes the value of the Arraylist returned by a function?

Tags: android, multithreading, thread-safety, java-threads

My defined function returns a JSONObejct Arraylist, however, when I instantiate a new Arraylist to the output of the function, it shows an empty Arraylist. How can I fix this issue and why is it showing an empty array list when it is indeed returning an Arraylist in the function?

Here is the code :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      setContentView(R.layout.activty_departures);

      departure_flights = doGetRequest();
}

//my function

private ArrayList<JSONObject> doGetRequest() {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        ArrayList<JSONObject> departureObject = new ArrayList<>();
        String url = "http_url";

        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

                if(response.isSuccessful()) {

                    try {
                        String jsonData = response.body().string();
                        JSONObject Jobject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
                        JSONArray jarray = Jobject.getJSONArray("Flights");

                        for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String adft = object.getString("Adft");
                            if (adft.equals("D")) {
                                departureObject.add(object);
                            }
                        }
                        

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        });

        return departureObject;
```

Comment: May I see your JSON response? might be have something wrong there like you made any mistake while casting.

Comment: Actually now when I went through the code again, I saw that I am initialising departureObject Arraylist outside of the onResponse function, but adding the values inside the onResponse function. Hence when I try to access from outside the method it retunes an empty list. How can I access the updated Arraylist from outside the onResponse function?

Comment: can it be a threading issue? since I am using enqueue()  in my doGetRequest() function

Comment: I added an answer please check it might help you. If not pls let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hitting Api in android not getting immediately return data it depends upon your response.
you are to return the list immediately so you received an empty list if you can work inside the onResponse method then your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `.equals()` method on `String`, but use `.contentEquals()`. The reason for this is because `contentEquals()` checks the content of a String and compares it to `StringBuffer`, `StringBuilder` and `CharSequence` aswell and all derived classes of these.

This is why in your case `adft.equals("D")` could return false even though adft is in the background this:

```
String adft = "D";
```

The reason for that is because `equals()` will only compare String objects, so all other objects are considered `not equal` and it will return false.

More on that here: https://www.programmersought.com/article/2993983603/

Also, sometimes returned values can store a space we dont need, so insted `"D"` we have `"D "` or `" D"`. To solve this just use method `.trim()`

```
if(adft.trim().contentEquals("D"))
```

Comment: Actually now when I went through the code again, I saw that I am initialising departureObject Arraylist outside of the onResponse function, but adding the values inside the onResponse function. Hence when I try to access from outside the method it retunes an empty list. How can I access the updated Arraylist from outside the onResponse function?

Comment: I don't think that's an issue. Because for onResponse your departureObject ArrayList is a global variable and it can be accessed there. You would get a whole different error if you weren't able to access it there. Another solution is that you don't retrieve ArrayList at all. Just make your departure_flights global as it is and in response add items in that ArrayList and make your doGetRequest() void.

Comment: How can I put the items in an arraylist within a function which is declared globally?

Comment: above onCreate declare it like this: List<JSONObject> departure_flights, then inside onCreate use this: departure_flights = new ArrayList<>();, then inside your doGetRequest() and onResponse use: departure_flights.add(object)

Comment: When I do that, departure_flights is still empty

Comment: Can it be an issue caused by multithreading? Since I am using enqueue?

Comment: Did you change equals to contentEquals?

Comment: Then adft is never equal to D. Check that, check the value of adft in if statements.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the list immediately after enqueue your API. Your ArrayList fill after API request succeeds so you have to create your ArrayList global and fill that after onSuccess. After that create another method to render your data on UI. like mentioned below:

```
ArrayList<JSONObject> departureObject = new ArrayList<>();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      setContentView(R.layout.activty_departures);

      doGetRequest();
}

private void doGetRequest() {

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    String url = "http_url";

    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

            if(response.isSuccessful()) {

                try {
                    String jsonData = response.body().string();
                    JSONObject Jobject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
                    JSONArray jarray = Jobject.getJSONArray("Flights");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String adft = object.getString("Adft");
                        if (adft.equals("D")) {
                            departureObject.add(object);
                        }
                    }
                    
                        reloadData();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }); 
}

private void reloadData() {
    // here your data is ready
}
```

Comment: if doGetRequest function returns void then how can it be instantiated to an array list?

Comment: The ArrayList object will have to be global to access that outside the function.

Comment: what do I put in the reloadData function?

Comment: You will do, What you want to do once the data is received from API like populate data on recyclerview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228115/discussion-between-m-muzammil-and-ian-bell).